# how to create a merge between two data frames on two columns without introducing additional rows in the left one?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames
DF1

| colA | colB | colC | colD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

DF2

| colA | colB | colE | colF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

The first two columns in both data frames are made up of the same quantities with some differences.
In DF2 colA has let's say M numbers each of the M numbers can have N properties so colB captures those. effectively the number of rows in DF2 is M*N. I must also mention the colE and colF are unique for each of the MN combinations.

IN DF1 colA has M different possible values but each of the M values may be repeated a different number of times
So if M runs through m1---mM then the total number of possibilities can be
k1*m1 + k2*m2 + K3*m3 and so on. k_{i}'s are integers.
In colB for each of the repeated M different values, there can be different or same values of N. However, unlike DF2 in DF1 same values of M and N can repeat (the uniqueness of rows is guaranteed by the other columns in DF1).

When I join these two tables in Pandas using the following merge command I get additional rows (in the join) which I am wondering how I can avoid?

```
pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on=['colA', 'colB'])
```

I am wondering if someone can suggest an answer using pandas which may be faster than me trying to make a dict of MN combinations that exist in DF1 and then pick the columns from DF2 and then paste back into DF1.

DF1

| colA | colB | colC | colD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | -10 | -20 |
| 1 | B | -33 | -44 |
| 1 | A | -22 | -11 |
| 2 | B | 33 | 44 |

DF2

| colA | colB | colE | colF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 123 | 456 |
| 2 | B | -1 | -2 |
| 1 | A | -4 | -5 |
| 2 | B | -7 | -8 |

my required merge

| colA | colB | colC | colD | colE | colF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | -10 | -20 | 123 | 456 |
| 1 | B | -33 | -44 | -1 | -2 |
| 1 | A | -22 | -11 | 123 | 456 |
| 2 | B | 33 | 44 | -7 | -8 |

Thank you for your time to read along.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```py
pd.concat([DF1, DF2[['colE', 'colF']]], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks user17242583 but that seemed to not work. I get incorrect values